# Minio or S3 simple web browser?

Tags: amazon-s3, minio

I am using minio to store files in front of my app

My users told me that the browser is very limited : they cannot preview/edit the files directly (given that they upload small text files and images, this seems ok for the requirement)

My instinct tells me that this is by design, the minio goal is not to provide this tool.

So I start looking for alternatives, however everything I've looked at is either dead or client-side (destop) or too complex.

Does someone knows a web app that is more or less like the minio web browser with a preview on the right (and the capacity to edit the file when it is a .txt|.md|.json|.yaml|...)

Answer (score 1):

Up to now (I searched for) there is no **free** good web browser even as good as minio browser itself.
But for accessing files and be able to modify them you (or your clients) can `mount` a bucket or a whole partition on their OS and then work with it like a regular file.

- pretty easy to upload files (just drag and drop)
- pretty easy to make bucket (just create directory)
- etc

In fact it will be a **real-time active mirror**.

And you can do it by using :

- [rclone](https://rclone.org/)
- FUSE

  - Windows [win-fsp](http://www.secfs.net/winfsp/)
  - Linux you will have it by default

And Linux it is simple, on Windows you can run:

```
rclone mount s3w:/windows/ E: --vfs-cache-mode full --dir-cache-time 0m5s
```

which means mount *windows* bucket on s3w (=alias) for S3c locally in a partition with *E:* with full access and every 5 seconds make sure it is refreshed.

screenshot
On a Windows server I have mounted `/windows` bucket.

[image]

Comment: it seems interesting, however I am using Mac computers and I dont understand what you should do with fuse or rclone ?

Comment: @ChristopheBlin, install `fuse` on Mac and install `rclone` then config `rclone` and mount it, it works the same.